# Using Koa with bluebird and pg

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, bluebird, koa

I have a question about the best way to use Koa with Postgres. I also (really) like using Bluebird, so I've gone with this approach.

```
'use strict'; 

var db = require('./modules/db.js');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){

    yield db.withConnection(function *(client){

        let id = this.request.query.id;
        let simple_data = yield client.queryAsync('select name from table1 where id = $1', [id]);

        this.response.body = simple_data;
    }.bind(this));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

This is the `db.js` file, basically it uses things mentioned in the Bluebird docs.

```
... bla bla, some imports

Promise.promisifyAll(pg);

function getSqlConnection() {
    var close;
    return pg.connectAsync(connectionString).spread(function(client, done) {
        close = done;
        return client;
    }).disposer(function() {
        if (close) close();
    });
}


function* withConnection(func){
    yield Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function (client){
            return Promise.coroutine(func)(client); 
    });
}

module.exports.withConnection = withConnection;
```

Do you have any suggestions on improving this. I really like it for now, I've tested it extensively (under load, making errors/exceptions, etc), and it seems to work correctly. I'm pretty new with these generators and other ES6 stuff, so it's possible that I'm missing something.
My question is basically why so little people use this approach (i find it hard to find examples on this online)?

I'm also fine with using other libraries besides pg and bluebird, but i like those due to the number of downloads they have,I prefer using popular stuff because i find it easier to find blog posts, help and documentation for those. Thanks!

Comment: In my Koa apps, I use `co-pg` which wraps the `pg` module to expose a promise interface, so `co-pg`'s source code might put you on the right track. I have a basic Koa 1.x app that demonstrates how I like to use Koa with Postgres: https://github.com/danneu/koa-skeleton/blob/master/src/db/index.js (also check out the my `db/util.js` file).

Answer (score 1):

Bluebird is a promise library, a very good one at that, but it should not be used as a guidance of how or what database library to use. All that `Promise.promisifyAll(pg);` stuff is actually quite poor next to all the promise solutions that exist out there - knex, massive.js, pg-promise, etc.

And if you want the best combination of `pg` + `bluebird`, then try [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var options = {
    promiseLib: promise // Use Bluebird as the promise library
};

var pgp = require("pg-promise")(options);

var db = pgp('postgres://username:password@host:port/database');

db.query('select name from table1 where id = $1', [1])
    .then(function (data) {
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    });
```

The library supports ES6 generators also, so you can write the code exactly like in your example.

From [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) example:

```
db.task(function * (t) {
        let user = yield t.one("select * from users where id=$1", 123);
        return yield t.any("select * from events where login=$1", user.name);
    })
    .then(function (events) {
        // success;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // error;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try pg-native.

From pg module docs:

> "node-postgres contains a pure JavaScript protocol implementation
>   which is quite fast, but you can optionally use native bindings for a
>   20-30% increase in parsing speed. Both versions are adequate for
>   production workloads. To use the native bindings, first install
>   pg-native. Once pg-native is installed, simply replace require('pg')
>   with require('pg').native."

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres